# python sqlite3 logic (for console server and command)

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to return some commands to my partner in sqlite3 db in python.
As my partner needs me to write a function to return command, I need some idea from the logic to write the function.

First I write the thing that maybe useless.

```
def readrouter():
    function = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type = ?  or  function = ?　ORDER BY key ASC"
    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print(read)
    conn.commit()
```

I have learned that now I am trying to connect to server but it can't return my variable function and print it out.

Should I make parameter for the function and how should I write it?

---

thanks for help and now i fix it with:

```
def readswitch(function,read):



    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    function = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type = ?  or  function = ?　ORDER BY key ASC"
    cur.execute(function)
    read = cur.fetchone()
    for row in read:
    print(read)
    conn.commit()
```

is there any mistake and  `def readswitch(function,read):` shows that the function and read [Parameter 'function' value is not used]

where is my mistake?

---

@ Paul Rooney

for the meaning of the function

```
 function = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type = ?  or  function = ?　ORDER BY key ASC"
```

is to select some kinds of commands by different function
for example:
My partner want to select a vlan command
then i will search the function which is "create vlan" 
and the usage of type is to provide some command which is global use (enable, conf t)
For the command , i will print out:

```
('enable',)
('configure terminal',)
('vlan (number)',)
('name (vlan name)',)
```

now , should i make two variables to fill in the "?"

like:

```
function = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type = " +x+"  or  function = " +y+ "　ORDER BY key ASC"
```

---

In the Parameterized queries  http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/ 
I do not know what is the meaning of `uId = 1` and i change it to x=1
what will be happen?
now i correct it like:

```
def readswitch(function,read):

    x=1
#
    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    function = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =:function 　ORDER BY key ASC",{"function":x}
    con.commit()

    cur.execute(function)
    read = cur.fetchone()
    for row in read:
     print read.row[0], row[1]
```

Comment: Where did the variable read come from?

Comment: here is a basic python sqlite tutorial http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/. I think you are getting confused. You seem to be doing a SELECT query, which is for reading data from a DB and then calling commit, which is for sending changes. Try using `read = cur.fetchone()` then `print(read)` maybe?

Comment: @PaulRooney: Not even doing a SELECT. Just assigning a SELECT statement to a variable, and then not using it.

Comment: Yep just noticed that. Needs a `cur.execute(function)` as well.

Comment: update the code in the question please. How does your updated code run?

Comment: @ Paul Rooney ok now but it shows nothing

Comment: You also need to pass a tuple of parameters to cur.execute, as your query requires them. That is what the '?' characters denote. Look at the tutorial in the section 'Parameterized queries'

Comment: @tommy please read the example in the tutorial. This will help you. Do not do it the way you propose, as this is bad practice in a real world situation you could be left open to an SQL injection attack.

Comment: @ Paul Rooney Thank you for your suggestion and I have read the Parameterized queries. And now i correct it like this

Comment: @tommy `uId` is a variable specific to that example, it has no place in your code. Your query contained 2 question marks implying that there are 2 parameters to go into your query, the type and the function, these should probably be passed  into your function? You should ask your partner to verify this. I think the confusion factor is growing here.